# Getting Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket when running python script

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am building an application that needs to read video data from a network camera using rtsp link.Its a automatic licence plate recognition project.here is thepython script that read video data:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@2022@115.127.67.229:554/trackID=1')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('camera view', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.namedWindow("test")
        image_counter = 0
        while True:
            image, image_frame = cap.read()
            if not image:
                print('failed to capture image')
                break
            cv2.imshow('test capture', image_frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
                print("Escape hit, closing...")
                break
            elif k % 256 == 32:
                image_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(image_counter)
                cv2.imwrite(image_name, image_frame)
                print("{} written!".format(image_name))
                image_counter += 1
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

camera is running and playing the video. but for getting the Qt management error cant do still capture. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I havent installed Qt packages,this will solve it